# get substring between 2 characters in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, regex, arrays, serialization

First of all, I tried to search it on SO but couldn't find a solution. I have a string

```
var str = 'a:5:{i:0;s:1:"1";i:1;s:1:"2";i:2;s:1:"3";i:3;s:1:"4";i:4;s:1:"5";}';
```

I want to grab all numbers between " " as an array in javascript. I tried this suggested on one of the SO questions.

```
console.log(str.split(/[""]/));
```

but this outputs

```
["a:5{i:0;s:1:", "1", ";i:1;:", "2", ";i:2;s:1:", "7", ";i:3;s:1:", "4", ";i:4;s:1:", "5", ";}"]
```

which is not exact.

Actually that above string is an array of PHP stored in MemcacheD and I am retrieving it in Node.JS and that's why I can't use json_encode or so. I am not good at Regex. So Experts please show some shine on it.

The result of above string should be an array or string like this

```
str = "1,2,3,4,5";
```

or an array like

```
array = [1,2,3,4,5];
```

Comment: That looks a bit like a `bencoded` string (but it's not)? What is the encoding?

Comment: I don't know. I just got this string in Node.js using its extension Memcached. This is an array stored by PHP in memcached.

Comment: That would be really useful to know, as there may be a decoder available in javascript.Which would be much better than a RegEx.

Comment: I wish there was. But currently I think I have to go with regex get it like 1,2,3,4,5 and then split it into an array.

Comment: `memcached` is `Python` thing isn't it?

Comment: that's a php array generated with [serialize](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) and memcached is an in-memory cache, you can connect to it from anything.

Comment: Great! Then there is probably a `php.js` version of `unserialize` then.

Comment: Thanks to all of guys. I think Matt has suggested good one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, this is a PHP [serialized](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) string. There is a version of [unserialize](http://phpjs.org/functions/unserialize/) available for javascript in the [`php.js`](http://phpjs.org/) project.

So using that function.

Javascript

```
var str = 'a:5:{i:0;s:1:"1";i:1;s:1:"2";i:2;s:1:"3";i:3;s:1:"4";i:4;s:1:"5";}';

console.log(unserialize(str));
```

Output

```
["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
```

On [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/CXtux/)

And if you are using nodejs then you could also consider a module like [`php-unserialize`](https://www.npmjs.org/package/php-unserialize)

Comment: Oh man that's good but don't you think using regex would be a better option instead of such long code?

Comment: IMO, I would say nope.

Comment: Great Xotic, Thanks for suggesting module

Comment: No problem. The nodejs module basically uses the function provided on `php.js` just wrapped as a module. :)

Comment: I tried your suggested jsFiddle, but it fails when handling substrings with alphabets like this 'a:7:{i:0;s:1:"1";i:1;s:12:"John Smith";i:2;s:19:"My Life Begins Here";i:3;s:31:"This is my .Picture.jpg";i:4;s:10:"1988-07-26";}'; Any solution?

Comment: I finally went with php-unserialize module. Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: Because the serialized data that you provided is incorrect, it should be `'a:5:{i:0;s:1:"1";i:1;s:10:"John Smith";i:2;s:19:"My Life Begins Here";i:3;s:23:"This is my .Picture.jpg";i:4;s:10:"1988-07-26";}';` and then it gives an output `["1", "John Smith", "My Life Begins Here", "This is my .Picture.jpg", "1988-07-26"]` as can be seen http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/7hL4h/

Comment: Hey Matt it's strange that everything is working great but only such array it hungs **a:5:{UID:s:1:"1";EM:s:19:"johnsmith@yahoo.com";PSW:s:40:"123a5123a5123a5123a5123a5123a5123a5123a5";NAME:s:11:"John Smith";PIC:s:31:"123a5123a5123a5123a5123a512.jpg";}** why? I used your provided Fiddle and php-unserialize module as well but both give exception

Comment: it's php session data stored in memcached. I do notice there is a difference but can't that be handled?

Comment: Try your string online at [http://www.functions-online.com/](http://www.functions-online.com/unserialize.html), or at [http://blog.tanist.co.uk/](http://blog.tanist.co.uk/files/unserialize/), or at [http://i-tools.org/](http://i-tools.org/unserialize). Your string seems to have a problem again.There are even more available online if you google for them.

Comment: If it is session data then `php-unserialize` proveds a special method for that format called `unserializeSession` which performs PHP's [`session_decode`](http://se2.php.net/session_decode)

Comment: really? Let me check it please

Comment: And I believe there is a phpjs version too, https://github.com/vianneyb/phpjs/blob/master/functions/var/session_decode.js But this is a link to a forked project, you would have to investigate where it lives in the main project.

Comment: Thanks Matt this worked great. Thanks for your kind support man

Comment: No problem and it's `Xotic750` and not `Matt` :P

Comment: OH really sorry man actually had another discussion with someone Matt :p

Answer (score 3):

```
str.match(/"\d+"/g).join().replace(/"/g,'')
// "1,2,3,4,5"
```

Comment: Matt is it possible to append a keyword like **user** to each of result like the output should be "1user,2user,3user,4user,5user"? please see if possible

Comment: @CodeDevil `str.match(/"\d+"/g).join().replace(/"(\d+)"/g,"$1user")`

Comment: why your regex does not work if there are alphabets in string like this 'a:7:{i:0;s:1:"1";i:1;s:12:"John Smith";i:2;s:19:"My Life Begins Here";i:3;s:31:"This is my .Picture.jpg";i:4;s:10:"1988-07-26";}' even though they just like previous one in between "" e.g: "John Smith"?

Comment: Please @Matt have a look at this issue

Comment: @CodeDevil Two reasons: 1) Your question said 'I want to grab all **numbers** between " "' 2) `\d` matches only digits. If you want to generalize, this would appropriately be a separate question as the strategy would be different. (If it were a simple change, I'd be happy to share it.)

Comment: well What if I update my question? because otherwise others will down vote and close my question. I tried removing \d but that didn't work.

Comment: @CodeDevil I don't understand - if you open up a completely separate StackOverflow question, why would others downvote and close it?

Comment: Ok let me make an other question.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22107547/get-substring-between-two-characters-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

```
function match_all(str, re) {
    var ret = [], v;
    while(v = re.exec(str)) {
        ret.push(v[1]);
    }
    return ret;
}
var str = 'a:5:{i:0;s:1:"1";i:1;s:1:"2";i:2;s:1:"3";i:3;s:1:"4";i:4;s:1:"5";}';
var numbers = match_all(str, /"(\d+)"/g);
console.log(numbers);
//to convert the result to ints
console.log(numbers.map(function(v) { return +v; }));
```