# Get Substring between two characters in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, regex, json, arr

After searching SO and other articles (all in vein) a few days before I asked a question about getting **numbers** between two characters using Javascript only. But unforunately I wanted to grab **substring** not just numbers from a string using javascript only. I have this string

```
var str = 'a:7:{i:0;s:1:"1";i:1;s:12:"John Smith";i:2;s:19:"My Life Begins Here";i:3;s:31:"This is my .Picture.jpg";i:4;s:10:"1988-07-26";}'
```

and solution to grab only numbers from string this works great

```
str.match(/"\d+"/g).join().replace(/"/g,'');
```

but this doesn't work if we need to grab substring, I tried removing \d from regex but that didn't work.

What is wrong I am doing? The output of this can be something like this

```
 //An array like this
 array = ['1','John Smith', 'My Life Begins Here', 'This is my .Picture.jpg', '1988-07-26'];
```

Actually that above string is an array of PHP stored in MemcacheD and I am retrieving it in Node.JS and that's why I can't use json_encode or so. I am not good at Regex. So Experts please show some shine on it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14867835/get-substring-between-two-characters-using-javascript

Comment: No @RobSedgwick that's different I tried that

Comment: What substring are you looking for?

Comment: Oh, Okay. Well always worth putting that in your question. The first thing we do is look to see if it's a dupe. Good luck.

Comment: It seems to me you are generating a string with PHP `serialize()` and passing it to JavaScript. Why don't you use `json_encode()` instead and pass to JavaScript a struct that is in fact written in JavaScript synthax?

Comment: @Havenard please see I have updated my question for what you said

Comment: I think this is what you really need. https://www.npmjs.org/package/php-unserialize "JavaScript tool to unserialize data taken from PHP. It can parse "serialize()" output, or even serialized sessions data."

Comment: I wanted to do it with regex not using any external library

Comment: RegEx don't have what it takes to parse this information properly for the same reason [you cannot parse HTML with RegEx](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/156811)

Comment: but @Havenard what if can parse this like the has suggested regex. This generates exactly the same?

Comment: The serialized data can countain multiple layers (arrays inside arrays) and RegEx is simply incapable of handling that. It also can have characters inside strings that may be interpreted by RegEx as the string delimiter while that might be not the case. Also, RegEx face everything as a string, even the numbers, while that might be not the case either. It is specially important in JavaScript because while 1+1 is 2, "1"+1 is 11.

Comment: Oh great notice. I just ignored that @Havenard. Thanks man this really something important to consider Specially characters inside Strings.

Comment: @Havenard I am really happy that you pointed that

Comment: And now I definetly would go with npm php-unserialize module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this? It will still break with escaped \" characters.

```
str.match(/".*?"/g).map(function(str) {
  return str.substring(1, str.length - 1);
});
```

Comment: Yes but substring should be in ' ' and one thing that your regex removes . from substring like This is my .Picture.jpg is becoming like  This is my Picture

Comment: No, it doesn't remove dots

Comment: thanks for your help but your regex is giving this '1','John Smith','My Life Begins Here','This is my Picture','1988-07-26'

Comment: Are you sure you are testing on the same string as in the example?

Comment: Oh My GOD! My mistake. That works great thanks Sabof Thanks alot.